# help in proving boundedness

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence is defined by S=1/1+....+${1\over\sqrt{n}}$ - 2*$\sqrt{n}$. I am trying to prove the sequence is convergent. 
answer: first I proved the sequence is monotonic Sn+1 - Sn < 0,
${1\over\sqrt{n+1}}$ - 2*$\sqrt{(n+1)}$ + 2*$\sqrt{(n)}$,

${1\over\sqrt{n+1}}$ - ${2\over\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{(n)}}$,

${1\over\sqrt{n+1}}$ - ${2\over\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{(n)}}$ < ${1\over\sqrt{n+1}}$ - ${2\over\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{(n+1)}}$,

thus Sn+1 - Sn < 0.

second: I am trying to prove it is bounded, but ended up with a variable bound. can somebody give me a hint on how to start.

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what's supposed to go where,  try enclosing your LateX in dollar signs, and making sure it appears the way you want it to be

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\int_1^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\le1+\int_1^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}
$$